# Reload update text from txt file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I create simple chat with no reload page. I update txt file from text in input. Data in txt file looks like:

```
some text 1
some text 2
some text 3
```

I try display all text from file, my code looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
        var html = [`
        <?php
        $myfile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
        while(!feof($myfile)) {
              echo '<div class="main-msg-wrapper">'.fgets($myfile).'</div>' ; 
            }
            fclose($myfile);
        ?>
        `];
        $("#chat").append(html);
    },1000); 
</script>
```

This code work, but i have one problem. If i add new value it is added, but display only when refresh all page (even though the code updates the page every 1 second with content from the file)

1. I reload page, code display:

```
some text 1
some text 2
some text 3
```

2. I add new text `some text 4`
3. Code is add to txt file
4. Code still displays the:

```
some text 1
some text 2
some text 3
```

5. I refresh page, code display the:

```
some text 1
some text 2
some text 3
some text 4
```

Comment: PHP by definition is server side. Hence page reload will be necessary in your current implementation.

Comment: PHP runs on server. You can not do what you are trying. You have to use fetch or Ajax.

Comment: You could also look into "short polling" or "long polling" to accomplish this.